# Notification on sent out email using EWS

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have done streaming notification on new arrival email but when ever user send any email to anyone, Can it generate any event though streaming, pull, push notification. I am trying to track each and every email body that is being sent out from account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Send notification that gets fired however when a user sends an email the default behaviour is to save a copy in the SentItems folder so if you subscribe to the CreateItem event on the SentItems folder that should probably cover what your trying to do (you can test that without writing any code using the EWSEditor).

You can configure the Email Client to not save a copy in the SentItems folder and if the user is trying to hide something they may delete it before you can get at it. Transport Agents or Jornaling should be used when you need to do this kind of thing for auditing/compliance reasons because it ensure you always capture the message.

Comment: Ok, I am doing streaming notification for inbox folder, Can I use that for both folder like inbox and sent Items. or Do i need to create another streaming notification for different folder.

Comment: Thanks @Glen Scales, It is working now as per your suggestion. Here I would like add something that we need two streaming subscriber to track two different folder as per my suggestion but if some one comes with better idea than it would be great to know that.